# Webbrowser Control in c# save dialog issue

Tags: c#

I am using a web browser control to download a file while clicking button in a web page,and save in my own folder.

The issue is that when I tried to download a save dialog pop up is coming. I have tried several code but not sucesss. I have given my code below.

```
HtmlElement Loginbutton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnLogin");
           if (Loginbutton != null)
           {
               Loginbutton.InvokeMember("click");

           }
 HtmlElement okbutton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("linkPDFResult");
            if (okbutton != null)
            {
                okbutton.InvokeMember("click");
            }
```

I want to download the PDF report to my folder without showing the save dialog control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the link out of the `HtmlElement` and then download the file with `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(...)`.